# Program type already present: com.google.firebase.iid.zzd

Tags: android-studio

I have tried to find out solution from last 3 hours but didn't find any.
I can build gradle but can't compile to build apk file.

Code Snapshot

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xerstech.test"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        }

   ...

dependencies {   
    implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0"
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0"
    implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0"
    implementation "com.android.support:design:28.0.0"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-core-utils:28.0.0"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0"

    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:28.0.0"
    implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5'
    implementation files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
}
```

Comment: Can you add the code as a formatted text as well as the detailed stack trace?

Comment: I have updated my question